# SQL (PLSQL) number a set of rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I attended an interview recently and the interviewer asked me number the occurrences of 'A', 'B', 'C' and so on. To put in table and columns - there is a table tab with column as col. The values in col is 'A', 'B', 'C' etc.

```
create table tab226 (col varchar2(3) );

insert into tab226 VALUES ('A');
insert into tab226 VALUES ('B');
insert into tab226 VALUES ('C');

insert into tab226 VALUES ('B');
insert into tab226 VALUES ('A');
insert into tab226 VALUES ('C');

insert into tab226 VALUES ('C');
insert into tab226 VALUES ('A');
insert into tab226 VALUES ('B');
```

The expected output is :

[image]

Interviewer told me I can use SQL or PLSQL to achieve it. I thought about it for almost 10 mins but couldn't come up with a plan let alone the solution. Does anyone know if this can be achieved in Oracle SQL or PLSQL?

Comment: scratch the post - I definitely forgot some other points in that question, I guess I remember only few points. But the above can be achieved by row_number() (partition by order by)

Comment: Wow! Thats fast! I did not expect such fast response. I will definitely try to remember the complete question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't make much sense to me, but - would this do?

```
SQL> select col,
  2    count(*) over (partition by col order by rowid) exp_output
  3  from tab226
  4  order by rowid;

COL EXP_OUTPUT
--- ----------
A            1
B            1
C            1
B            2
A            2
C            2
C            3
A            3
B            3

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks for being so fast :)

Answer (score 1):

As written, you cannot accomplish -- consistently -- what they are asking for.  The problem is that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no way to run a query on the original data and preserve the ordering.

However, the final column appears to simply be an enumeration, so you can use `row_number()` for that:

```
select col, row_number() over (partition by col order by NULL)
from tab226;
```

But if you have an ordering column -- say `id` in this example -- then you would do:

```
select col, row_number() over (partition by col order by NULL)
from tab226;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9e8373d18d29672b5543af3d998f6bee) is a db<>fiddle.